# Using a flip-phones GPS NMEA data for the GPS in an APRS station

Tags: aprs, gnss

I have heard that it is possible to connect certain flip-phones to external devices via their Micro USB port and, through the USB port, send the NMEA location Data from their internal GPS to an external device.

I am wondering if it would be possible to use a GPS and Micro USB equipped flip-phone in this way to receive the GPS NMEA location data for an APRS station.

Comment: Was there a particular phone you had heard of that had this feature?

Comment: @PaulV the Kyocera Dura XT: http://www.kyoceramobile.com/duraxt/#specs

Comment: Any modern Android device is capable of doing this. It's called an OTG cable.

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto Even pushing the NMEA GPS output to another device through the OTG cable?

Comment: It would likely require the right program running on the device...

Answer (score 2):

This question was answered in part at [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5501719/544198) for an Android device. As they are getting to be quite inexpensive, I assume it will work for your needs. Here are some parts to your solution:

1. Use an OTG cable to connect your phone to your other device.
2. The phone needs to run a program called "ShareGPS ", which will communicate the location over USB.

Feel free to look at the question to see a solution for TCP/IP, Bluetooth, etc.